sql for float to int value in live
how to convert bigint values to float in live for sql
i try to convert int to flaot value for outuput
CONCAT(SUM(book_sales."2022" + book_sales."2021" + book_sales."2020" + book_sales."2019" + book_sales."2018")/1000000, 'M') 


In "live"? Do you mean Oracle Live SQL? Or are you using another DBMS? Which? And you want to convert to FLOAT? An approximate data type? Are the values so big that an exact numeric data type does not suffice? This seems unlikely. Is your issue that your DBMS applies integer division instead of a real division? If so, it may suffice to divide by 1000000.0 instead, so that the involved decimal number leads to decimal division. The data model looks a bit weird with one column per year. There should better be a column instead indicating the year and then one row per year.

Try with
CONCAT(CAST(SUM(book_sales."2022" + book_sales."2021" + book_sales."2020" + book_sales."2019" + book_sales."2018") as float), 'M') 

